# fprintf inserts random Next Lines?

Tags: c, string, filewriter

I'm trying to write a really simple program that takes the data from one file "RAW Image file" to another file bit by bit.
Except when it's written to the new file, it needs to be HEX and also needs to specifically only be (640*6) = 3840 characters per LINE after which it should NEXTLINE and start from 0 to 3840 again.

If I look at my file with n Text editor I should see 3840 chars in each line for 480 lines.
My problem is I keep on getting random Next lines and I cant figure out why? Is it maybe because some of the bits together might look like Next lines chars when using `Printf`?
I have tried dumping it all to a file using `WRITE()` as well but I structure it with a Buffer array but still is does the same thing AND ALSO writes bit for bit which doesn't print as HEX.

The code here is just to give you an idea, I've pulled of some cowboy moves to try and manipulate it into getting to do what I want but nothing works.. Some of it might not make sense at all.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <fcntl.h>
//#include <unistd.h>

char *readFile(char *fileName);

int main()
{
    char *pix;pix = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    char Buff[1843201];
    char pix8[7];
    //int x=0;

    FILE *fpw;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    fpw=fopen("NewBmp.bin", "wb");
    pix = readFile("test.bin");

    int y,z,ByteC;
    unsigned long x;
    for (y=0;y<=(480);y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<=(3840);x+=2)
        {                       
            Buff[(480*y +x)]=pix[(480*y +x)];
            ByteC = pix[(480*y +x)];
            ByteC |= (unsigned char)((pix[(480*y +x+1)])<<4);   //<<--Prototype

            fprintf(fpw, "%x",(unsigned char)ByteC);                            
        }
        Buff[(480 * y)+1]='\n';
        fprintf(fpw,"%c","\n");


    }
    //fwrite(Buff , 1 , 1843201 , fpw );
    fclose(fpw);
}

char *readFile(char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char *code;
    size_t n = 0;
    int c;

    if (file == NULL) return NULL; //could not open file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long f_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    code = malloc(f_size);

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        code[n++] = (char)c;
    }

    code[n] = '\0';        

    return code;
}
```

Comment: Since you're already reading the file 1 byte at a time, why wouldn't you just immediately print the hex value to the other file and keep a count so you know when to print a newline.  This whole thing seems overly complicated.

Comment: I hesitate to post this as an answer because I am not sure I understand the whole question, but it seems like something like this would do what you want: http://ideone.com/zIuyhl  If you need to handle different sized images you could adjust it to take the filenames and width/height on the command line.

Comment: `code = malloc(f_size);` --> `code = malloc(f_size + 1);` to handle `code[n] = '\0';`  Also good to add `fclose(file);`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but I think `fprintf(fpw,"c","\n")` should be `fprintf(fpw,"%c","\n")` instead. And why not just`fprintf(fpw, "\n")`.

Comment: Hi yea I eventually replaced fprintf with fputc(10,fpw); anyway.

Comment: @BaddaBoompshhh I see. If you found the solution already you can post an answer to it and mark it as solved.